# What happens to the investments into my city if I join another one?

Tags: shopheroes

I have played alone so far and made some considerable investments into my city, that you get during the Tutorial. If I join a city created by other players, what happens to the investments in my own one? Will those have been in vain or will they be saved until I leave the other city?

Answer (score 1):

Your investmest will be transfered to your new town.

Comment: Do you have a source for this, or is this based on your own experience?

Comment: 1. My own experience

Comment: 2. in game tips

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's still relevant, but still:

When you join another city, all of your investments travel with you, so there's clearly an advantage to get to a city with a lot of players for combined total investments. However, there's a penalty of 10% of your total investments that is applied when you leave a city in a 10 days period after joining it. To be more specific, the percentage diminishes based on how many days you've spent in the city. So, basically, if you leave a city on the 1st day, you'll lose 10%. On the second day, you'll lose 9% and so on. Leaving a city on 11th day is completely safe since you won't lose anything.